# Include PowerShell Workflow Scripts in a Workflow

Tags: powershell, powershell-workflow

I have several Workflow scripts defined.
I want to write a master script to reference the dependent scripts.
I am expecting there is some kind of Import or Include statement to reference the dependent scripts and make the workflows available.

How do I make this work ?

Example:
**dependent.ps1**

```
workflow doSomething
{
   Write-Output "Hello World"
}
```

**master.ps1:**

```
Import dependent.ps1
workflow master
{
   doSomething
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can include the contents of another script in to your script via [dot sourcing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts?view=powershell-6#script-scope-and-dot-sourcing):

```
. .\dependent.ps1

workflow master
{
   doSomething
}
```

You could use a loop to do this for several scripts and even use `Get-ChildItem` to discover them programmatically:

```
$ScriptsToInclude = Get-ChildItem \path\to\your\scripts\*.ps1

ForEach ($Script in $ScriptsToInclude.Fullname) {
   . $Script
}
```

Comment: that does the trick locally, how do I make this work in Azure Runbooks ?